# GluonMobile's AutoCompleteTextField scrolling doesn't work as expected

Tags: javafx, mobile, scroll, autocomplete, gluon

When I type something in *AutoCompleteTextField* it shows me a drop-down list with suggestions based on my input. If there is too much items a scroll bar appears on the right of the drop-down list. But the scroll only works on Windows desktop and only by using a mouse wheel. On mobile touch devices (android, iphone) *AutoCompleteTextField* always reacts as if I **select** an item (touch) from the drop-down list, not **scroll** (slide): the moment I touch the drop-down list and start sliding it up or down - it closes, and if my finger was pointing to an item the control selects it. The same thing happens when I try to move the scroll bar with mouse pointer on desktop (Windows and macOS).
The code is trivial:

```
@FXML
private AutoCompleteTextField<String> field;
```

...

```
field.setCompleter(s -> {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).startsWith(s)) {
            res.add(String.valueOf(i));                                
        }
    }
    return res;
});
```

No *ResultNodeFactory* is provided, so the drop-down list is populated with *Labels* by default. Same happens when providing a custom *ResultNodeFactory*.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: *update*: I've noticed that when scrolling enough fast I can actually see the suggestions list scrolling while it fades and disappears, it happens within a second maybe.

Comment: When you tap to start scrolling on a mobile device, you are sending a mouse clicked event, and this is processed by the item target of that event. In this case, accepting the selection and closing the issue. I've filed an issue on this to allow both scrolling and tapping/selecting in the autocomplete popup.

Comment: Thank you, will wait for a fix. JFYI: playing with MouseTransparent property had no effect, I suppose it's because this property affects *all* mouse events, but in our case we need to handle them selectively.

Comment: Do you have a link so I could track it?

Comment: No, I don't, sorry, it is an internal issue tracker.

Comment: Oh, ok. Could you please drop a line here to let me (and possibly others) know then when it's closed?